# Help interpreting a logical formula

Tags: logic, formal-systems

I encountered a formula in a [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2268172), and i need help interpreting it:
[The original formula as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Ely.png),
it is in the middle on page 4 of the PDF at the link

i am concerned with the second formula in the image. From earlier in the paper we know that $R_2^{(2)}$ is set union, the $x_1$,$x_2$,... are sets of real numbers,
~ is negation, etc.

Exchanging the symbols for more familiar alternatives i arrive at:

$$\forall A\left( \exists B\neg\left[ A \cup B = B\right]\rightarrow\exists C\exists D\left(\left[\neg C\cup D = D\right]\land \left[A\cup C=A\right]\right)\right)$$

I tried to stay as close to the paper as possible while improving readability.
The paper says this statement is **false** under the given interpretation (sets of real numbers etc), **because** there are sets with exactly one element. I do not understand this reasoning.

for A = {n} = C, B = D = $\emptyset$, where n is some real number, the formula seems to evaluate to true.

I feel like i might be misinterpreting the scope of the negation operator because it is used once inside, and once outside brackets, in both cases the scope being an equation. assuming common order of precedence shouldn't these be identical? 
What am i missing?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I'm puzzled also... The leftmost sub-formula (that you translated as $A \cup B=B$) means that $A \subseteq B$. Thus, negating it is meaningful: $A$ is **not** a subset of $B$. But in the second occurrence the negation sign *seems* to apply only to t he predicate... Maybe a typo ?

Comment: on page 3 it is said that he understands 'sentences' as 'equations' (x=y) combined with logical operators (negation,conj., disj.), so as far as the grammar they define there is no sense of negation of a predicate. since i don't seem to be missing something obvious (or we are both missing it), i suppose indeed it must be a typo somewhere in there